# first sort the result then group by the resultset in mysql

Tags: mysql

my database is

```
 id  fileId version
   1  1       1.0
   2  1       1.1
   3  2       1.0
   4  2       1.1
   5  2       1.12
```

the required result set is

```
   id   fileId version
    2    1       1.1
    5    2       1.12
```

i try by this "select distinct fileId, version from tablename order by fileId desc "

Comment: What is the data type of `version`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT f1.id, f1.fileID, f1.version
FROM files AS f1
LEFT JOIN files AS f2 
ON f1.fileID = f2.fileID
AND f1.version < f2.version 
WHERE f2.fileID IS NULL
```

Also for better speed it is advised to use index on id and fileID

```
ALTER TABLE `files` ADD INDEX ( `id` ) 
ALTER TABLE `files` ADD INDEX ( `fileID` )
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
select fileid, max(version)
from t
group by fileid;
```

Comment: its dosen't work correctly, the corresponding fields on the row are not sorted correctly. plz check the resultset, i edited,